# Computation of $(\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla)\textbf{u}$ in the Navier stokes equation: inner or outer product?

Tags: matrices, vectors, products, outer-product

The [Navier Stokes equation](https://www.britannica.com/science/Navier-Stokes-equation) for an
**incompressible** flow of a **homogenenous** fluid reads
    \begin{align*}
 \nabla\cdot \textbf{u} &= 0\\
 \rho \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\textbf{u} + \rho(\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla)\textbf{u} &= -\nabla p + \mu \nabla ^2 \textbf{u}
 \end{align*}
Regarding, 
$$(\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla)\textbf{u}
$$
the two components of this term are: 
$$
\textbf{u} = \begin{bmatrix}
u \\ v
\end{bmatrix}  \quad \text{and}  \quad 
\nabla = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial }{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial }{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the sign $\cdot$ being the dot product. However in the example that I was given, the computation has been done as follows:
\begin{align*}
(\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla)\textbf{u} &= \Big(\begin{bmatrix}
u \\ v
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial }{\partial x} & \frac{\partial }{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}\Big)\begin{bmatrix}
u \\ v
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
where $\begin{bmatrix}
u \\ v
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial }{\partial x} & \frac{\partial }{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}$ is an **outer product** (Notation: $\otimes$ and not a dot product $\cdot$) and hence a matrix. So for me, the notation $\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla$ is misleading. What am I getting wrong?

**Example**
Compute the acceleration of a fluid at $(x,y) = (1,2)$ at time $t = 2$. with velocity $(u,v) = (1, x^2t)$

**Fluid acceleration**
    $$
 \frac{D\textbf{u}}{Dt} = \frac{\partial \textbf{u}}{\partial t} +(\textbf{u} \cdot  \nabla) \textbf{u}
 $$

**solution** (given to me): 
    \begin{align*}
 \frac{D\textbf{u}}{Dt} &=\frac{\partial \textbf{u}}{\partial t} +(\textbf{u} \cdot  \nabla) \textbf{u}\\
 &=\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\begin{bmatrix}
 1\\x^2t
 \end{bmatrix} +
 \Big( 
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1\\x^2t
 \end{bmatrix} 
 \cdot 
 \begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
 \end{bmatrix}\Big)
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1\\x^2t
 \end{bmatrix}\\
 &=\begin{bmatrix}
 0\\x^2
 \end{bmatrix} +
 \begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\partial 1}{\partial x} &  \frac{\partial 1}{\partial y}\\
 \frac{\partial x^2t}{\partial x} &  \frac{\partial x^2t}{\partial y}
 \end{bmatrix}\cdot
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1\\x^2t
 \end{bmatrix}\\
 &=\begin{bmatrix}
 0\\x^2
 \end{bmatrix} + 
 \begin{bmatrix}
 0 &  0\\
 2xt &  0
 \end{bmatrix}\cdot
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1\\x^2t
 \end{bmatrix}\\
 &=\begin{bmatrix}
 0\\x^2
 \end{bmatrix} + 
 \begin{bmatrix}
 0\\2xt
 \end{bmatrix}\\
 &=
 \begin{bmatrix}
 0\\x^2 + 2xt
 \end{bmatrix}\\
 \end{align*}

Now if I try to compute firs the dot product inside the parenthesis (instead of the outer product, as it was proposed in the answers), I get
\begin{align*}
&=\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\begin{bmatrix}
 1\\x^2t
 \end{bmatrix} +
 \Big( 
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1&x^2t
 \end{bmatrix} 
 \cdot 
 \begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
 \end{bmatrix}\Big)
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1\\x^2t
 \end{bmatrix}\\
&=\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\begin{bmatrix}
 1\\x^2t
 \end{bmatrix} +
 \Big( \frac{\partial 1}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial x^2t}{\partial y}\Big)
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1\\x^2t
 \end{bmatrix}\\
&=\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\begin{bmatrix}
 1\\x^2t
 \end{bmatrix} +
 \Big( 0 + 0 \Big)
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1\\x^2t
 \end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\x^2
 \end{bmatrix} +
 \Big( 0 \Big)
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1\\x^2t
 \end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
 0\\x^2
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: many thanks for @user76284 and md2perpe for your answer. I tried to implement those answers and compared it to the answer given to me in the exercice. What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: This is not correct:
$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1&x^2t
 \end{bmatrix} 
 \cdot 
 \begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
 \end{bmatrix}
= \frac{\partial 1}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial x^2t}{\partial y}
$$
Look at what I have written in my answer!

Comment: Also, there is a matrix multiplication error in the answer you had been given. Here's the correct one:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 1\\x^2t
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 1\frac{\partial}{\partial x}&1\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\
 x^2t \frac{\partial}{\partial x}&x^2t \frac{\partial}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Be really careful with the order when you multiply things with operators!

Comment: @md2perpe The given answer completely bungles the dot product. It should be row vector ($u^T$) times a column vector ($\nabla$), and it needs to produce a scalar (not a matrix) differential operator as the result. Or perhaps a scalar operator multiplied by the identity matrix, if you squint.

Comment: @greg. Are you referring to my last comment? It was a bad decision of me to call it "the correct one". What I meant was that as a matrix multiplication (removing the dot which shouldn't be used between matrices) that is the result. It isn't what should be used in the formula for the fluid acceleration, though. In that way it isn't "the correct one".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$\eqalign{
x &= \pmatrix{x\\y},\quad u = \pmatrix{u\\v}=\pmatrix{1\\tx^2} \\
}$$
Then the *matrix-valued* gradient $\,G=(\nabla u)^T$ has components
$$\eqalign{
G_{ij}
 &= \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} 
\;=\; \pmatrix{
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
  \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
 }
  = \pmatrix{0&0\\2xt&0} \\
}$$
and can be used to write the material derivative as
$$\eqalign{
\frac{Du}{Dt}
  &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + Gu \\
  &= \pmatrix{0\\x^2} + \pmatrix{0&0\\2xt&0}\pmatrix{1\\tx^2} \\
  &= \pmatrix{0\\x^2} + \pmatrix{0\\2xt} \\
  &= \pmatrix{0\\x^2+2xt} \\
}$$
which can be evaluated at $\;(t,x,y)=(2,1,2)$
$$\eqalign{
\frac{Du}{Dt} &= \pmatrix{0\\1^2+2(1)(2)} = \pmatrix{0\\5} \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer @greg. I indeed got the same answer. However my question is how to interpret the expression $(\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla)\textbf{u}$, as there is a dot product inside the parenthesis whereas actually you are talking about a matrix valued gradient?

Comment: You can evaluate the expression by performing the dot product and then derivative operation (md2perpe's answer shows how to do that). Or you can to the derivative operation first, and then the dot product (my answer shows how to do that). Either way leads to the same result.

Comment: ok so in a whole we can say that the two notation, the one that you used $G = (\nabla \textbf{u})^\top$ and the one in the question $\textbf{u} \cdot \nabla$ are equal?

Comment: No. I am calculating $G$ which handles all of the _derivative_ operations, and then taking the normal dot product with the resulting matrix, i.e. $\,u\cdot(\nabla u)$. The alternative is to calculate a scalar differential _operator_ $\,L=(u\cdot\nabla)$ and apply it element-wise as $Lu = (u\cdot\nabla)u$. The order of the parentheses is important to the interpretation, but the final result is the same in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Either the computation has been done incorrectly or you have misunderstood it. It should be
$$
\begin{align*}
(\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla)\textbf{u} 
&= \Big(\begin{bmatrix}
u & v
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial }{\partial x} \\ 
\frac{\partial }{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
\Big)
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\ v
\end{bmatrix}
\\
&= \Big(
u \frac{\partial }{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial }{\partial y}
\Big)
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\ v
\end{bmatrix}
\\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
\\ 
u \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: if I implement your method I get $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\x^2\end{bmatrix}$, which is not the correct anwer

Comment: @ecjb. How do you know it's not the correct answer?

Comment: Multiplying by a matrix, instead of a scalar, in the second line might be a clearer notation
$$
\left[
\matrix{
\left(u \frac{\partial }{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)&0
\\
0&\left(u \frac{\partial }{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)}\right]
\cdot
\left[
\matrix{u\\v}
\right]
$$

Comment: ok i get it. many thanks for your comment @greg. However why do you use $u\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ and not $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$?

Comment: @greg. Probably, but he needs to learn to handle both matrices and operators correctly.

Comment: @ecjb. Notice the order of multiplication of operators: $u$ and $v$ come to the left of $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$. When multiplying operators you have 
$$f(x,y) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \neq \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your efforts @md2perpe. I just tried to upvote your answer but I can't unless you modify your answer

Comment: @ecjb. If I knew what to modify I would do it.

Comment: @md2perpe: solution1: modify whatever, i upvote and you backmodify. solution2: do nothing

Comment: @ecjb. I just added a whitespace. I don't know if that was enough.

Comment: @md2perpe that was indeed enough

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla$ is the dot product of a vector $\mathbf{u}$ and a "vector" $\nabla$. Thus it should be interpreted as a "scalar". Therefore $(\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{u}$ is a scalar multiplication of the "scalar" $\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla$ and the vector $\mathbf{u}$. In other words,

\begin{align}
((\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{u})_i
&= (\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{u}_i \\
&= \left( \sum_j \mathbf{u}_j \nabla_j \right) \mathbf{u}_i \\
&= \sum_j \mathbf{u}_j \nabla_j \mathbf{u}_i
\end{align}

Notice that $(\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{u} \cdot (\nabla \mathbf{u})$, where $\nabla \mathbf{u}$ is an outer product between the "vector" $\nabla$ and the vector $\mathbf{u}$:

\begin{align}
((\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{u})_i
&= (\mathbf{u} \cdot (\nabla \mathbf{u}))_i \\
&= \left(\sum_j \mathbf{u}_j (\nabla \mathbf{u})_j\right)_i \\
&= \left(\sum_j \mathbf{u}_j (\nabla_j \mathbf{u})\right)_i \\
&= \sum_j (\mathbf{u}_j (\nabla_j \mathbf{u}))_i \\
&= \sum_j \mathbf{u}_j \nabla_j \mathbf{u}_i
\end{align}